# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99]) using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database, sqlalchemy

I am trying to transfer my panda's data to MySQL database using sqlalchemy and pymysql I am able to create an engine using sqlalchemy using the below code:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:XXXX@localhost/indics')
```

But when I try to read the table of the above database using the below code

```
df=pd.read_sql_table("waterlevel",engine)
```

it is showing the following error:

```
"perationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")"
```

I tried restarting the MySQL server but it didn't help

Comment: Perhaps try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: tried  that too but its showing same error